# C++ code compiles without include

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

Why I don't need to include cstdlib and how do I disable this? I'm using Code::Blocks with GCC compiler on Windows 7.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like `cstdlib` is included by `iostream`. This seems to be the case on GCC 4.7.3 at least.

Comment: Your question seems to be part of a general (mis-)understanding that when a documentation says "If you do X, you can do Y", you assume that you have a guarantee that not doing X causes Y to be an error. That isn't the case most of the time. You still have to do X in order to *prove* that Y is legitimate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to include `<cstdlib>` because it (or the part of it containing `system()`) was included by `<iostream>`. It is unspecified whether or which other (standard) headers are included by standard headers. You cannot disable this behavior but should be aware of it to avoid portability problems between different standard library implementations.

You should not depend on this behavior and include `<cstdlib>` yourself. You should also use `std::system` instead of the global `system`. Functions from `<c*>` headers are only guaranteed to be in the `std` namespace (the global ones, on the other hand, in the `<*.h>` headers).

Answer (score 3):

I am using MS Visual Studio 2012 and in it, <`iostream>` includes `<istream>` which includes `<ostream>` which includes `<ios>` which includes `<xlocnum>`. `<xlocnum>` includes `<cstdlib>`, so your program indirectly includes `<cstdlib>`

Although the sequence of includes might be different in other compilers and/or implementations, the reason that this code runs is that `<iostream>`, either directly or indirectly includes `<cstdlib>`.

It should be noted the the libraries that `iostream` includes are implementation-specific and the code might not compile in some other compiler. As a general rule, the libraries that a header file includes are not usually well-documented or part of the standards, so do not rely on indirect includes. If you need a library, include it directly and, since standard libraries are [include guarded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), no significant [overhead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_%28computing%29) will be inflicted on your program's compilation or run-time.

Comment: You make it sound like the indirect inclusion has to be there in all implementations. This is not the case.

Comment: Will you be a little more specific?

Comment: I mean it is possible that `iostream` does not pull `cstdlib` in, but you make it sound like it always does.

Comment: I also believe that the libraries that `iostream` includes are implementation-specific. But in this case, since `iostream` is the only header file that the program includes, the reason that the code runs must be that `iostream` pulls `cstdlib` in. However, I will update the answer to reflect this in a more clear way. Thanks for the feedback.